# Test Driven Development/Integration Testing in RIA development

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing, rich-internet-application

When working with RIA development, there's at least three critical levels that should be tested:

- RIA application classes - in Flash/Flex these could be tested using AsUnit, FlexUnit or any other JUnit-like solution
- RIA application interface - in Flash/Flex this could be done using FlexMonkey
- RIA application server integration - ?

Anyone who has experiences, ideas, information, links, booktitles etc to share about unit testing/integration testing the RIA development workflow?
I'm especially interested in resources on testing the server integration. (I use PHP on the server side and Flash/Flex for the client, but any general thoughts would be much appreciated!)

Jonas

Comment: What method do you use to communicate with the backend? REST? SOAP? Know that would make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% on what you are looking for but I am going to attempt to answer this anyways. (After writing this answer I also realized this is a freaking old post, so you might already have your answer :) )

If you are looking to make sure that the **client integrates with the server correctly**, you can do **automated end-to-end testing using a UI automation tool**, like *Selenium* (there are others, we use Selenium and we have been happy with it).

We actually have two levels of testing for the UI. We have ***smoke*** tests and ***acceptance*** tests.

For both of these we will deploy our app, set up the environment and run tests that simulate user actions on the UI.

Our **smoke tests** are designed to do a **breadth** of testing but not going too deep into functionality. They make sure our app installs, the ui comes up, users can log in and function in the app reasonably. So this basically attempts to make sure the app is not utterly broken and unusable.

Our **acceptance tests** run a lot longer and only once a day. These are more like automated regression tests that make sure that most of the functionality of our app works as expected (Breadth + Depth of testing)

I hope this helps at all.